# Sorting file contents into a list in Python

Tags: python, file-io

So I'm working with a .txt file, and I'm trying to sort all the numbers into a list of integers.

My file looks like this.

```
21
32
54 65
128
38 92 155 21
54
```

And I want my output to be:

```
[21, 32, 54, 65, 128, 38, 82, 155, 21, 54].
```

How do I do this?

Comment: based on your expected output, it doesn't see to be sorted? If you want it to be sorted, pease update your post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the `split` method:

```
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as file:  # replace filename.txt with your filename
    data = file.read().split()
    data = [int(x) for x in data]  # this will convert all of the numbers to integers

print(data)
```

Output:

```
[21, 32, 54, 65, 128, 38, 92, 155, 21, 54]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.split()`, but that will give a list of strings.  To convert, you can use `[int(number) for number in numbers]` or `list(map(int, numbers))`:

```
with open("myfile.txt") as f:
    numbers = f.read().split()
    integers = list(map(int, numbers))
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to read all numbers from text file, sort and store them in list, you can try this code snippet:

```
data = []
with open('input.txt', 'r') as fp:
    for line in fp.readlines():
        _lineData = line.split(' ')
        for num in  [int(f) for f in _lineData if f != '']:
            data.append(num)
data.sort()
```

Contents of input.txt

```
21
32
54 65
128
38 92 155 21
54
```

Your output based on content of text file will be as:

```
[21, 21, 32, 38, 54, 54, 65, 92, 128, 155]
```